# lattice plot functions do not work with mids (mice output)

Tags: r, lattice, density-plot, r-mice

I have a dataset with missing values and therefore run the `mice` function as a imputation method. Until here everything worked fine.
Now I want to compare the distribution of original and imputed dataset with the `lattice` package using `xyplot`, `densityplot` or `stripplot`. But none of those plots work. I always get the error:

> no applicable method for 'xyplot' applied to an object of class "mids"

Here is my code so far.

```r
install.packages("mice")
library("mice")
tempData <- mice(data_impute, m = 5,maxit = 50,seed = 500)

summary(tempData)
tempData$imp$min.observed 

#compare distribution of original and imputed dataset - does not work so far
install.packages("lattice")
library("lattice")

xyplot(tempData, min.observed ~ overall + slide + transfer, pch = 18, cex = 1)
densityplot(tempData)
```

`tempData` is my dataset with the imputed data. And `min.observed` is the variable which hat missing values and is imputed. Overall, `slide` and `transfer` are variables which had no missing values.

Comment: try to make your code reproducible, e.g., by adding a dummy dataset. As the example in the docs works `imp <- mice(boys, maxit=1); xyplot(imp, hgt~age|.imp, pch=c(1,20),cex=c(1,1.5))` this would be helpful, to see what is going wrong.

Comment: Try `with(tempData, xyplot(min.observed ~ overall+slide+transfer,pch=18,cex=1)) `